# Не выводит return

Tags: javascript

```js
const coursesSet = {
  courses: ['HTML', 'CSS', 'JavaScript', 'React', 'PostgreSQL'],
  getCourses() {
    return this.courses;
  },
  addCourse(courseName) {
    this.courses.push(courseName);
    for (let course of this.courses) {
      if (this.courses.includes(course)) {
        return 'Ви вже маєте такий курс';
      }
    }
  },
};
coursesSet.addCourse('Jue');
coursesSet.addCourse('CSS');
console.log(coursesSet.getCourses());
```

Comment: А теперь чётко вдумчиво внятно с расстановкой, объясните что есть, что надо, что не получается, каков результат необходим, а не вот это вот всё

Comment: Нужно чтобы когда добавляешь похожее название курса, выводило сообщение, что такой курс уже существует Если вводим CSS , а он уже есть в массиве, то должен возвращаться return

Comment: Куда возвращаться? ну вон он, возвращается. Что не так?

Comment: Сообщения нет же, когда я добавляю еще один CSS? А добавляет еще один CSS  в конце хотя он в массиве уже есть

Comment: А где оно должно появиться?

Comment: При выводе в консоли

Comment: а где у вас вывод в консоль для addCourse?

Comment: Спасибо, понятно! Сорри, только начинаю))

Comment: Надеюсь поняли.... отлично......  тогда пару нюансов укажу по текущему коду.... 5 мин подождите

Comment: 1. Для проверки в массиве - цикл не нужен.... то есть можно писать сразу  `if (this.courses.includes(courseName)) { ....` .......... 2. эту самую проверку нужно будет сделать **до вставки в массив** ............ 3. Лучше делать в таком случае не `return` а выбрасывать исключение

Comment: Уже поняла, что не нужен

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас не правильно реализована проверка. Сначала надо проверить, а уже затем добавлять.

Вот пример реализации:

```js
const coursesSet = {
  courses: ['HTML', 'CSS', 'JavaScript', 'React', 'PostgreSQL'],
  getCourses() {
    return this.courses;
  },
  addCourse(courseName) {
    // Проверяем наличие
    if (this.courses.includes(courseName)) {
      // есть, сообщаем об этом
      return 'Ви вже маєте такий курс';
    } else {
      // Нету, добавляем
      this.courses.push(courseName);
      return 'Курс добавлен'
    }
  },
};

console.log(coursesSet.addCourse('Jue'));
console.log(coursesSet.addCourse('CSS'));
console.log(coursesSet.getCourses());
```

**UPD** из комментариев
И еще пара примеров, как можно организовать код:

Из метода **addCourse** убран лишний `else`, т.к. `return` прерывает дальнейшее выполнение кода и возвращает результат.

> Декомпозиция задач

**addItem** отвечает за добавление элемента
**addCourse2** отвечает за проверку наличия элемента в массиве

```js
const coursesSet = {
  courses: ['HTML', 'CSS', 'JavaScript', 'React', 'PostgreSQL'],
  getCourses() {
    return this.courses;
  },
  addCourse(courseName) {
    if (this.courses.includes(courseName)) return 'Ви вже маєте такий курс';
    this.courses.push(courseName);
    return 'Курс добавлен'
  },
  // Два новых метода с декомпозицией задач
  addItem(courseName) {
    this.courses.push(courseName);
    return 'Курс добавлен'
  },
  addCourse2(courseName) {
    return this.courses.includes(courseName) ? 'Ви вже маєте такий курс' : this.addItem(courseName);
  },
};

console.log(coursesSet.addCourse('Jue'));
console.log(coursesSet.addCourse('CSS'));
console.log(coursesSet.addCourse2('Vue'));
console.log(coursesSet.addCourse2('CSS'));
console.log(coursesSet.getCourses());
```

Comment: можно `else` не писать в данном случае..... т.к. return уже прервёт весь код

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Да понятно, что можно код ужать еще, но для начинающего, так понятнее. И вообще возврат строк, как результат работы... брр, я бы просто true/false возвращал при необходимости. И классом бы оформил )

Comment: ну в комментах я написал что лучше исключение кидать.......... для новичка может и понятно, но неправильно) научится так неправильно писать и будет везде ненужные конструкции впихивать)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский А как кидать в исключения вместо return?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Скорее вопрос: **а зачем** кидать в исключение вместо return?

Comment: @VladimirGonchar потому что "ошибка что такой элемент есть" - это исключительная ситуация, очевидно ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯   ....... вот если бы метод должен был обязан что-то возвращать по контракту (длину массива, например) - одно, а когда внутри происходит доп. операция - это уже исключение........

Comment: @NatashaPodobriy  `throw new Error('Тут текст');`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский С чего бы? Ожидаемое поведение "нашёл элемент, если есть - пропускаем, максиум выводим что-то, если требуется". Исключения быть не может – как минимум потому что оно оборвет выполнение программы, если не отлавливать. А отлавливать – это уже излишний код.

Comment: @VladimirGonchar как скажете... можете все программы без единого исключения писать. Я вас не принуждаю........... ЗЫ: даже банально в доках в бросании ошибок вполне подобные примеры есть https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw ...... но вы пишите ретурны, чтоб меньше кода было

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Я не говорю, что они не нужны. Но их нужно использовать грамотно. Не надо обмазываться "трукачами" на любой чих) И опять же, в примере в доках невалидность данных = исключение (что правильно, потому что неверные параметры могут сломать логику), здесь же не та ситуация, и исключение скорее вредит.

Comment: @VladimirGonchar то есть когда пытаются впихнуть уже существующий элемент (читай как "невалидный" ..... словарь в помощь что значит valid), то это нормально, а когда тоже самое делают в другом месте - не нормально......окей. запомним. ........... *" это может сломать логику"* --- а в примере в доках не ломает логику. потому что.....?   странная у вас логика. тут исключение что-то ломает, а там не ломает...... Г - Логика

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Потому что недобавление элемента, если он уже есть, не сломает логику. А конечный результат будет достигнут - элемент существует в списке на выходе. Другое дело, если бы неисполнение условия ломало бы дальнейшую логику.